# Spaces around search when replacing with RegEx

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to perform a replacement.  Consider the following string:

```
Please replace something in this sentence.
and replace <b>something&nbsp;</b> in this sentence.
But not here http://www.mysite.com/something/mypage.html
Or here \\myserver\something\myshare\
```

I want to replace `something` with `somethingelse`, however `something` can appear in a URL or UNC in my source and I don't want to replace that. I also have some funny HTML going on.

This is the pattern I'm using:

```
\b[^/\\]Something[^/\\]\b
```

Which works, however I'm getting the spaces around the first `something` back as well.  If I replace `something` with `somethingelse` I get the result:

```
Please replacesomethingelsein this sentence.
and replace <b>somethingelse&nbsp;</b> in this sentence.
But not here http://www.mysite.com/something/mypage.html
Or here \\myserver\something\myshare\
```

The second instance works, the first with the spaces doesn't.

How can I ignore the presence or absence of spaces around `something`?  Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just get them with capturing groups and use them in the replacement?

Comment: I tried `\b[^/\\](Something)[^/\\]\b` but wasn't sure how to replace just the SubMatch. Is that what you're thinking?

Comment: See my answer for the use :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx

So:

```
ReplaceTest("\b([^/\\])Something([^/\\])\b", "$1SomethingElse$2")
```

**Note**: Didn't include the case insensitive search.

Comment: I verified this works. Both of you have correct solutions--not sure which to mark as the answer :)

Comment: @SLeepdepD I think Loamhoof's answer is more specific to VB, and mine is more generic.  Mine might help people with non-VB issues similar to yours.  I would mark Loamhoof's since it is closer to the bounds the original post laid out. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use look-behinds and look-aheads, so your regex should look something like this, 
`\b(?<!/\\)something(?=[^/\\])\b`.

Since you are including the `[^/\\]` in the regex, it is actually matching the char before the "something", this then includes it back in the response which you state you don't want.  When you want to confirm something is or isn't there (forward or back) and not have it actually match those pieces you validate on, you can use look-ahead and look-behinds to handle that validation.  For more information on look-ahead and look-behinds, I use [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) as a reference.

You can see the testing I did [here with your example you provided.](http://rubular.com/r/8BkcvdiICl).

EDIT: [Look-behinds are not supported in VBScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html), but it seems that look-aheads are supported fully.  Since the regex is using validation ahead and behind (which is redundant), it should still work using only the positive look-ahead (checking for the NOT condition you outlined): `\bsomething(?=[^\/\\])\b`.

Comment: I think `vbscript` doesn't support them.

Comment: @SLeepdepD I found some documentation saying look behinds are not supported but look-aheads are fully supported.  I edited the response and added a link to that find.  The look-ahead should still be enough.  The look-ahead is a "positive" look ahead matching on the "negative".  The "positive" look-aheads should work in VB.

Comment: "*negative look-ahead: \bsomething(?=[^\/\\])\b*" That's a positive lookahead in fact, not a negative. And also, that'd catch `myUrl/something `

Comment: I verified this works. Both of you have correct solutions--not sure which to mark as the answer :)